# How to check performance of parallel processing in matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, parallel-processing

Just to check how parallel processing works in matlab, I tried the below piece of codes and measured the time of execution. But I found the parallel processing code takes more time than normal code which is unexpected. Am I doing wrong somewhere?

Code with parallel processing

```
function t = parl()
matlabpool('open',2);
tic;
A = 5:10000000;
parfor i = 1:length(A)
    A(i) = 3*A(i) + (A(i)/5);
    A(i) = 0.456*A(i) + (A(i)/45);
end
tic;
matlabpool('close');
t = toc;
end
```

There result for parallel processing

```
>> parl Starting matlabpool using the 'local' profile ... connected to 2 workers. Sending a stop signal to all the workers ... stopped.

ans =

    3.3332


function t = parl()
tic;
A = 5:10000000;
for i = 1:length(A)
    A(i) = 3*A(i) + (A(i)/5);
    A(i) = 0.456*A(i) + (A(i)/45);
end
tic;
t = toc;
end
```

Result for without parallel processing code

```
>> parl

ans =

   2.8737e-05
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the time to (apparently) execute the serial version of the code, it is effectively `0`.  That's suspicious, so look at the code ...

```
tic;
t = toc;
```

Hmmm, this starts a stopwatch and immediately stops it.  Yep, that should take about `0s`.  Have a look at the parallel code ...

```
tic;
matlabpool('close');
t = toc;
```

Ahh, in this case the code times the execution of the closing of the pool of workers.  That's requires a fair bit of work and the time it takes, the `3.33s`, is part of the overhead of using parallel computation in Matlab.

Yes, I do believe that you are doing something wrong, you are not measuring what you (probably) think you are measuring. `tic` starts a stopwatch and `toc` reads it.  Your code starts a stopwatch twice and reads it once, it should probably start timing only once.